# Restore Amazon RedShift snapshot with same IP from

Tags: ip, amazon-redshift, restore, snapshot

Restoring Amazon Redshift from the snapshot. Redshift restored with different IP. Is there a way to control restoring Redshift with the same IP. The problem is client side is not aware of the IP change and each time it will be required to fix IP for client side which is really bad.

Thanks
Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is set up a route53 CNAME record to point a user friendly name to your existing redshift cluster.

Then , use that friendly name instead of the redshift cluster name within your application connection strings.

If you then need to restore redshift, do that and then update your route53 cname record to point to that newly restored (new) redshift cluster